# Cloud-solution for wordpress server overload

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have wordpress site on Linode VPS (Ubuntu 11.04). Site working fine, but sometimes i have Digg-effect (large numbers of simultaneous visits) and my site has down. I looking a cloud-solution that worked **only** when the linode-server can not process a large number of requests. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 6):

Simplest thing to do is place a caching server infront of wordpess, such as [varnish-cache](http://varnish-cache.org)

Or there are nginx + memcache setups that are also viable, at any rate reducing the amount of dynamic content generation will help alleviate a lot of the strain on your solution.

Update:  voretaq7's comment reminded me of the W3 Total cache plugin, this is a great plugin that allows you to take database and objects and cache them within word press using a variety of technologies.

Comment: Reducing your dynamic content generation should be step 1.  You'd be amazed how much your VPS can serve if it's only got to take the data off disk/out of RAM and hand it to the client.  It's the database-querying PHP-processing bit that kills sites.

Comment: http://fennb.com/microcaching-speed-your-app-up-250x-with-no-n

Comment: I tried to install varnish but it is not yet so.

Comment: @BohdanHdal You of course need to configure it, to run on port 80, cache lifetimes etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using something like CloudFlare as a CDN?

Comment: Thank you. I have already paid attention to CloudFlare. You know any alternatives of this service?

Comment: I think that if you google for CDN, you will find a lot of commercial alternatives. The wikipedia page on it has lots of alternatives listed too.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct mirrors Oneiroi's position... but to try and be creative, spin up cloud instances when under load and start issues temporary redirects to the cloud server's DNS name. Of course, anything generated still has to be sourced from over there, and thus already copied across the network.